# Error: HTTP Error: 404, Not Found when trying to deploy functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy some functions with this command "firebase deploy --only functions", for the firebase project ijn-amen.

```
=== Deploying to 'ijn-amen'...

i  deploying functions i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled... i 
functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled... ✔  
functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled ✔  
functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled i  
functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... i  
functions: packaged functions (49.35 KB) for uploading 
⚠  functions: Upload Error: HTTP Error: 404, Not Found

Error: HTTP Error: 404, Not Found
```

But when I'm trying with a another project by switching with "firebase use project-id", it works fine without getting this error.
I already tried to run "npm install -g firebase-tools" again and deleting .firebaserc.
I also run again firebase init but it's still doesn't work.
I trie to logout with firebase logout and login again with firebase login but it's still not work.

Here my firegbaserc:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "ijn-amen"
  }
}
```

Here my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

here my firebase.json:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

Comment: If the Firebase CLI is giving errors that are not helpful, contact Firebase support for assistance.  Make sure your CLI is fully up to date.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: It seems that your errors are project-specific, as Doug already stated I would suggest you to visit [Firebase Support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support)